# Include php file in Wordpress' functions.php not working for header.php

Tags: php, wordpress, require

I have included the line below in my `functions.php` file (at the top, also tried that line at the bottom of the code). I can access variables and all other stuff defined in that file in **all templates**. But when I try to `echo $something` from that file within the **header.php**, nothing shows up. No content, no error message.

```
require_once '/path/to/file.php';
```

Ok, after lots of trying I just found out that using the line from above inside the **functions.php** with

```
global $something;  
echo $somtehing;
```

in the **header.php** shows the value inside the wordpress header. `global $something` is not needed in template files though. Can please anyone explain me why?

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a shortcode and echo shortcode to header.php
https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

example

```
function foobar_func( $atts ){
    return "foo and bar";
}
add_shortcode( 'foobar', 'foobar_func' );
```

and call in header

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[foobar]'); ?>
```

Comment: I would need a solution to include a file once and use everything everywhere from header to templates to footer.

Comment: you can put shortcode to any file or the_content editer width shortcode, read the link Shortcode_API, pls

Comment: I have edited my question with a shortcode approach, but without success.

Comment: `[include filepath='/path/to/file.php']` not right. You can create a variable like my example, or read tip create shortcode here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

Comment: Thanks for your help, but looks like this goes beyond my skills :)

Comment: Tried another one, without success.

Comment: I  just don't understand why a simple `require_once '/path/to/file.php';`works in all templates but not inside the header or footer?

Comment: `require_once ` in wp difference width `include` or `require` for callding variable in file :). I think shortcode very easy for shows code any where.